# Is there any information on functions which contain a single even number in their range?

Tags: functions

I’m working with one variable functions which can only have one even number in their range and wanted to know if there is any current information regarding general properties of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange request indeed... can manufacture them at will by taking any $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by defining:

$$
g(n)
  = \begin{cases}
       2          & n = n_2 \\
       2 f(n) + 1 & n \ne n2
    \end{cases}
$$